# libxml_get_errors custom error handler

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

Hi
i've create a module that build a form from a valid xml, after form submission it rebuild an xml and validate it against an xsd schema. if the form have not been compiled correctly, it return to the form with all the error messages get by libxml_get_errors. the problem is that libxml_get_errors doesn't generate user friendly error messages. 
is there a way to extend the error handler to produce simpler and more user friendly error messages?

```
if (!$doc->schemaValidate($schema_riferimento)) 
{ 
  $errors = libxml_get_errors(); 
  foreach ($errors as $error) 
  { 
    array_push($global_errors, $error->message); 
    log_message('debug', "Errore di validazione: ".$error->message); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler" and "more user friendly" exactly? Can you make an example?

Comment: sure... a typical error generate by libxml_get_errors is this: "'piva_utente': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'IdentificativiRichiesta__piva_utente' is not accepted by the pattern '\d{11}'", i would like to display an error like "field xxx must be an 11 digits number", or something like this...

Comment: @Nextneed - where did you get the error message ?and are you sure is from libxml_get_erros not the xml itself?

Comment: @ajreal - yes, they are from libxml_get_errors, i push all the error messages into an array and send it to the form generator... if (!$doc->schemaValidate($schema_riferimento)) {
                $errors = libxml_get_errors();
                foreach ($errors as $error)
                {
                    array_push($global_errors, $error->message);
                    log_message('debug', "Errore di validazione: ".$error->message);
                }
            }

Comment: @Nextneed - you have the error code + message, is totally up to you how to do the display ... **10000% is a lame question**

Comment: @ajreal well, the issue is a valid one. `is not accepted by the pattern '\d{11}'"` is not an error message you can show to the end user. The question is how to translate that to plain english (or italian)... Not sure whether it's possible without complex translations

Comment: @ajreal - sorry for the lame question :) I think error code is not enough, the form can be very complex and i have to retrieve at least the node name that cause the error...

Comment: @Pekka you got the point, i know that maybe i can translate everything with some string substitution, but i'm searching a better approach...

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a hash in which you keep friendly error messages, keyed by the error code.

For instance:

```
$friendly_errors = array(
                       '0' => 'One friendly error message',
                       '1' => 'Another friendly error message
                   );
$friendly_error_message = $friendly_errors[$error->code];
log_message('debug', $friendly_error_message);
```

Simple.